# Product of sum expression

Tags: sequences-and-series, products

I am having a little trouble following an example I came across today which says that:

$$2 \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sum_{i=0}^{k-2} 1 = 2 \sum_{k=1}^{n} (k-1) = 2 \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} j$$

I have tried fidgeting around with the expressions, but I just don't follow the thought process here.  If anyone can please help me with some intermediate steps here, I will be very grateful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start by the interior summation, which is 
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{k-2} 1=\underbrace{1+1+\cdots +1}_{k-1\, \text{times}},
$$
k-1 times because there are the term when $i=0, i=1,\ldots , i=k-1$. So know you have
$$
2\sum_{k=1}^{n}(k-1)
$$

Take $j=k-1$. When $k=1,j=0$ and when $k=n,j=n-1$, yielding
$$
2\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}j
$$

Note that the $j=0$ term is useless, so you could always take it out, and you can explicitly calculate this sum with this formula:
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n j= \frac{n(n+1)}{2}.
$$
In your case, one gets 
$$
2\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}j=\frac{2(n-1)n}{2}=n(n-1)
$$

Comment: Fantastic!  Thanks a lot.  It seems so easy now :)

Comment: @Kristian Added some additional info

Answer (score 4):

We will take each step one by one
$\sum_{i=0}^{k-2} 1 = k-1$
Now since we are summing up 1 $k-1$ times we can directly replace it with the term $k-1$. Consider the second part.
$\sum_{k=1}^n k-1$
Now put $j = k-1$ in the above equation we get
$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} j$

Comment: Thank you very much.  I really overcomplicated this in my notes!  Now it looks so easy I almost feel ashamed for posting here!  Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

The first equality: You have $k-1$ summands (one for each $i=0, \ldots k-2$) of $1$, so you can replace the sum by $k-1$.
The second equality: An index shift. Instead of adding up $k-1$ for $k=1, \ldots, n$, you add up $j$ for $j=0, \ldots n-1$.

Comment: A more encouraging starting line could be "It's not that difficult". =)

Comment: Thank you very much!  Yes, it seems so obvious now :).  Really appreciate your help.